# SCRIPT ERROR in react javascript file in google maps API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, google-maps-api-3, runtime-error

getting this error->

**Script error.
at handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:48195:58)
at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:48214:7**

any suggestions
project working fine it shows google map and stuff only this error is coming on each refresh

```
useEffect( () => { 
    const loadGoogleMapScript = () => {
      try{
        const script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${env.GOOGLE_API_KEY}&callback=initMap`;
        script.async = true;
        script.defer = true;
        window.initMap = initMap;
        document.head.appendChild(script);
      }
      catch(error){
        console.error("Error while loading google maps script:", error);
      }
    };

      const initMap = () => {
       
        const mapOptions = {
          center: { lat: 0, lng: 0 },
          zoom: 0.641,
          minZoom: 0.641,
          disableDefaultUI: true,
          mapTypeControl: false,
          keyboardShortcuts: false,
          streetViewControl: false,
          mapTypeControl: false,
          mapTypeId: window.google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          restriction: {
            latLngBounds: {
              north: 85, // Set the northern boundary (latitude)
              south: -85, // Set the southern boundary (latitude)
              west: -180, // Set the western boundary (longitude)
              east: 180, // Set the eastern boundary (longitude)
            },
            strictBounds: false,
          },
          styles: [
            {
              featureType: "all",
              elementType: "labels",
              stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }],
            },
            {
              featureType: "landscape",
              elementType: "labels",
              stylers: [{ visibility: "on" }],
            },
            {
              featureType: "administrative.country",
              elementType: "labels",
              stylers: [{ visibility: "on" }],
            },
            {
              featureType: "administrative.locality",
              elementType: "labels",
              stylers: [{ visibility: "on" }],
            },
          ],
        };
  
        const panoramaOptions = {
          position: { lat, lng },
          pov: { heading: 0, pitch: 0 },
          zoom: 1,
          disableDefaultUI: true,
          showRoadLabels: false,
          linksControl: true,
          panoProviderOptions: {
            hideLogo: true, // To hide the Google watermark/logo
            disableCompass: true, // To disable the compass
            panoId: "gs_id:remove_labels",
          },
        };
  
        
        const map = new window.google.maps.Map(
          mapContainerRef.current,
          mapOptions
        );
        mapRef.current = map;
  
        
        const panorama = new window.google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
          streetViewContainerRef.current,
          panoramaOptions
        );
        map.setStreetView(panorama);
  
        window.google.maps.event.addListener(map, "mousemove", function (e) {
          map.setOptions({ draggableCursor: "crosshair" });
        });

        map.addListener("click", (event) => {
          placeMarker(event.latLng);
        });
      };
  
        if (!window.google) {
           loadGoogleMapScript();
        } else {
          initMap();
        }



}, [lat, lng]);
```

i tried various async and await unable to find the soluton

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) like a working codesandbox so that the community can check and debug on our end?